# Encounters Unable to load one or more of the requested types while doing Integration Test

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-1.1

I am doing Integration test for an asp.net core API with Target Famrwework 4.6 as the project requires some of my old 4.6 dll. I am getting the below error.

**Message: System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException : Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.**

**The error comes when I call await _client.GetAsync**

I have attached the StackTace image.[image]

My test Project is a class library framework 4.6.

**TestFixture.cs**

```
 public class TestFixture :IDisposable
    {
        private const string SolutionName = "Project.API.sln";
        private readonly TestServer _server;

        public HttpClient Client { get; }

        public TestFixture()
        {
            Assembly startAssembly = typeof(Startup).GetTypeInfo().Assembly;
            var contentRoot = GetProjectPath(startAssembly);
            var builder = new WebHostBuilder()
                .UseContentRoot(contentRoot)
                .UseEnvironment("Development")
                .UseStartup<Startup>();

            _server = new TestServer(builder);
            Client = _server.CreateClient();
            Client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:62455");
        }

        public string GetProjectPath(Assembly startupAssembly)
        {
            var projectName = startupAssembly.GetName().Name;
            var applicationBasePath = PlatformServices.Default.Application.ApplicationBasePath;
            DirectoryInfo directoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(applicationBasePath);
            do
            {
                var solutionFileInfo = new FileInfo(Path.Combine(directoryInfo.FullName, SolutionName));
                if (solutionFileInfo.Exists)
                {
                    return Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(directoryInfo.FullName, projectName));
                }
                directoryInfo = directoryInfo.Parent;
            }
            while (directoryInfo.Parent != null);
            throw new Exception($"Solution root could be located using application root {applicationBasePath}");
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            Client.Dispose();
            _server.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

**Test.cs**

```
 public class TransactionControllerTest :IClassFixture<TestFixture>
    {
        private string businessID = "1206";
        private readonly HttpClient _client;
        public TransactionControllerTest(TestFixture fixture)
        {
            _client = fixture.Client;
        }
        [Fact]
        public async void ProcessFinalTransactionProcess()
        {
            var response = await _client.GetAsync($"/v1/businesses/{businessID}/transactions/TestMe");
            Assert.NotNull(response);
        }
    }
```